# Php - Populate Select with oracle query values

Tags: javascript, php, html, oracle11g

I have three `<select>` tags in my HTML.

```
<select id = "deptSelect" onchange = "select1Changed(this.value)">
<option value = "1">Dept1</option>
<option value = "2">Dept2</option>
<option value = "3">Dept3</option>
</select>

<select id = "processSelect" onchange = "Select2Changed(this.value)">
<option value = "">Please Select</option>
</select>

<select id = "categorySelect" onChange = "Select3Changed(this.value)">
<option value = "">Please Select</option>
</select>
```

I want to implement a scenario such that on selection of a particular department, all related processes of that department are filled in `processSelect`, on selection of a particular process from `processSelect` all related categories of that process are populated on `categorySelect`

**Javascript**

```
function categorySelect(value)
{

var arg= value;
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
//alert ("Returned");
//Get value from php page that executes select statement into ProcessArray 
}
else 
alert("Nothing");   
}

xmlhttp.open("GET","fetch.php?q="+comboOption,true);
xmlhttp.send();

for(m = 0; m < ProcessArray.length; m++)
{
var option = document.createElement('option'); //On selection of this option, another query has to be executed and values has to be returned in categorySelect select
option.innerHTML = ProcessArray[m].name;
option.value = ProcessArray[m].code;
category.appendChild(option);
category.value = ProcessArray[0].code;     
}
```

**PHP:**

```
$q = intval($_GET['q']);
$i = 0;
$j;

$conn = OCILogon("abc","abc","abc_server");
$qry_process = "SELECT CATEGORYSHORTCODE, CATEGORYDESCRIPTION FROM tableAbcWHERE PROCESSid = ".$q;
$qry_category= OCIParse($conn,$qry_process);
OCIDefineByName($qry_category,"CATEGORYSHORTCODE",$CATEGORYSHORTCODE);
OCIDefineByName($qry_category,"CATEGORYDESCRIPTION",$CATEGORYDESCRIPTION);
OCIExecute($qry_category);

while(OCIFetch(qry_category))

{

$categoryArray = array(array($i,$CATEGORYSHORTCODE,$CATEGORYDESCRIPTION)); 

}
```

How do I return this `$categoryArray` and useit in my Javascript?

Comment: AJAX to a php that connects to the Oracle db and returns what you're interested in.

Comment: @TraianTatic Can you show me an exemple?

Comment: It's not that easy to be honest. I had myself to deal with a php to Oracle connection and I chose to export from Oracle to csv and the upload the csv on the server. Does the data you take from the db change often? I would recommend you to do the same, unless you find someone who can help you with the php to Oracle connection. It's close to impossible if your Oracle and php are not on the same host and your php is not updated to the latest version.